# Docker-compose for git-repository with concrete branch

Tags: git, docker-compose

I have a task to build containers from git-repository, using docker-compose.
For example:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

project:
  image: https://github.com/my_project.git
  container_name: my_project
```

And image to be upload not (only) from master-branch, but from any concrete branch.

I there any way to specify custom git-branch in docker-compose ?

Comment: The code snipet doesn't look like a docker-compose file.  What is it?

Comment: I update snippet to make it look more like docker-compose file

Comment: My point is that there is no `project:` top-level element as far as I know.  I've never seen reference to docker-compose interacting with git, there's certainly no description about it doing so in the compose-file [specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/).  It's odd that you are asking a question about branches when it can't interact with git at all.